# How to find the number of seconds elapsed from the start of the day in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df in which I have a column named time_column which consists of timestamp objects. I want to calculate the number of seconds elapsed from the start of the day i.e from 00:00:00 Hrs for each timestamp. How can that be done?

[image]

Comment: SO is not a free coding service [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)

```py
df['time_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_column'])
df['second'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_column'].dt.time.astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day. Can the same program be done in terms of minutes? That is, can there be a column that stores the no. of minutes elapsed from the start of the day. Please don't delete your current answer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @AnwesaRoy You can divide the total seconds by 60.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me answer this question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/72229250/19024581

Comment: @AnwesaRoy Sorry, I'm not good at plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Do df['time_column]. That will give you the time column. Than just do something like:

```
 import datetime as date
 current_date = date.datetime.now()
 time_elapsed = []
 for x in range(0, current_date.minute*60 + current_date.hour*60*60):
     time_elapsed.append((df['time_column'][x].minute*60 + df['time_column][x].hour*60*60)- (current_date.minute*60 + current_date.hour*60*60))
```

Comment: Dont  know if you wanted something like this

Comment: Hi, can you please help me answer this question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/72229250/19024581